# Проблема с одинаковыми компонентами слайдера на странице

Tags: javascript, vue.js, слайдер

Столкнулся со следующий проблемой: есть массив с данными, через цикл я вывожу данные в компоненты(у меня есть несколько компонентов(в каждом из них есть [слайдер](https://idangero.us/swiper/)) компоненты отличаются друг от друга наполнением и внешним видом, например текст по другому расположен,где-то два слайда на всю страницу, где-то три).Так же у каждого слайдера есть стрелки переключения.

Проблема в следующем, например мы добавляем на страницу `компонент1` с двумя слайдами на весь экран, ниже добавляем `компонент1` с пятью слайдами на  весь экран.  Переключая слайдер( с 2-мя слайдами) переключается слайдер(с 5-ю слайдами), как решить эту проблему?

**Слайдер использую [swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/)**

**Код:**

```
    <div v-if='fetData.design.content_template == "content_template_1"'>
        <ContentTemplate1 :fetData='fetData'></ContentTemplate1>
    </div>
    <div v-if='fetData.design.content_template == "content_template_2"'>
        <ContentTemplate2 :fetData='fetData'></ContentTemplate2>
    </div>
........
```

***ContentTemplate1***

```
    <div class="content_1_swiper_component">
            <swiper ref="content_1_swiper" :options="swiperOption">
                <swiper-slide class="swiper-slide" v-for="(item, index) in fetData.content" :key="index.id">
         <div>
    .....

</div>
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
        <div class="swiper-button-next content_1_swiper_btn_next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev content_1_swiper_btn_prev"></div>



export default {
        name: 'Content2',
        props: ["fetData"],
        data() {
            return {                
    swiperOption: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: '.content_1_swiper_btn_next',
                        prevEl: '.content_1_swiper_btn_prev'
                    },
}
```

Comment: без кода сложно понять, что за слайдер? Как он работает? На вскидку проблема в том, что работает глобально с классами у элементов, поэтому сразу все слайдеры переключаются

Comment: @ThisMan На вскидку верно, сейчас обновлю вопрос, добавлю код

Comment: @ThisMan обновил вопрос, добавил код

Comment: Вы пробывали без `vuejs` разместить два слайдера на странице и переключать их?

Comment: @РустамГимранов не пробывал, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Проблема в том, что классы работают глобально, как написали выше, что с этим сделать я не знаю

Comment: Зайдите на их сайт, там в примерах есть ссылки на гитхаб, перейдите скопируйте, монтируйте в обычную html страницу. Да и вообще api к слайдеру почитайте. Вам ThisMan указал возможную проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При использовании для слайдера `Swiper`, в качестве навигации, элементов
>   `DOM`, находящихся за пределами главного контейнера слайдера,
>   необходимо в настройках слайдера явно указывать **уникальные
>   селекторы класса** этих элементов, чтобы не допустить управления всеми экземплярами слайдера на странице одновременно.

Приведу пример, где реализована данная задача, т.е. слайды `Swiper` с различными настройками, вставлены на страницу как компоненты `vue` и работают без конфликта.

Посмотрите пример по ссылке - [vue swiper](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-yot7g?fontsize=14)